# CSAPP malloc implementation

Tags: c, malloc

I was recently reading CSAPP and I have a question about `malloc` implementation in CSAPP.

The macro `PREV_BLKP` is used to get previous block pointer by calculate current block size:

```
#define PREV_BLKP(bp) ((char *)(bp) - GET_SIZE(((char *)(bp) - DSIZE)))
```

But how can we get previous block pointer by current block size?

If previous block size and current block size are not the same then we will get wrong address by this macro right?

Comment: are not these blocks containing the same data type? how can the block sizes differ?

Comment: the `malloc` in question can support variable sizes allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [this code](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ics2/code/vm/malloc/mm.c), the size of the allocated block is packed into the block address by:

```
/* Pack a size and allocated bit into a word */
#define PACK(size, alloc)  ((size) | (alloc)) //line:vm:mm:pack
```

and the packed address is store in the `place` function by the `PUT` macro, so it can handle different sizes of blocks without overwriting anything.

```
static void place(void *bp, size_t asize)
     /* $end mmplace-proto */
{
    size_t csize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));   

    if ((csize - asize) >= (2*DSIZE)) { 
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        bp = NEXT_BLKP(bp);
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize-asize, 0));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize-asize, 0));
    }
    else { 
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it, PREV_BLKP get previous block size from previous block's footer, thanks!